# Selective macro expansion using the Boost/Wave C/C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, boost, c-preprocessor

For a C99 code base I am heavily depending on macros as a poor man's substitute for proper C++ templates. The most severe downside of macros for my use case is that it is hard/impossible to debug the generated code, which is a lot. It would be nice if I can create a custom preprocessor that only expands a white listed set of macro's as an intermediate build step. I was wondering if it is possible to do this using the Wave preprocessor from the Boost library. I am skimming through the docs, but to be honest it remains unclear to me if that is possible.

1) Conceptually I want to achieve something like:

```
foo.c => selective_wave_preprocessor(MACRO_BAR, MACRO_BAZ) => foo.c_preprocessed
```

So in this case `foo.c_preprocessed` would be the result of **ONLY** expanding (function-like) macro's `MACRO_BAR` and `MACRO_BAZ` in `foo.c`. And if I would run the normal preprocessor over `foo.c` and `foo.c_preprocessed` the output must be the same.

2) I would like to see that multi-line macros marked as white-listed are actually formatted with new-lines so that it remains human readable.

I was hoping if somebody can tell me if the Wave preprocessor is the right tool to do this at all. If so, I would much appreciate to see an example on how to do something like this or point me to the proper Wave primitives needed to accomplish this.

Comment: Note that [§5.1.1.2 Translation phases](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) lists backslash-newline removal as phase 2, so the preprocessor proper doesn't see the embedded newlines after the backslashes in the macro definition.  That makes 'preserving newlines' difficult.  It's also why the X11 `imake` program used `@@` to mark newlines; it post-processed the output from the C preprocessor to convert `@@` back into a newline.  I don't know the answer to the rest of the question; I've not played with Wave.

Comment: I don't know Wave either, but a brief scan through some of its docs suggests that there is no runtime configuration option for the standalone C++ preprocessor it provides that would make it avoid performing macro expansions that a conforming preprocessor would perform.  However, it might be possible to use the Wave classes to build your own custom preprocessor that would do so.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, forgive my lack of knowledge on precise compilation steps. So if I get your remark right, My problem requires a specialized lexer that does for instance the `@@` replacement trick so that my preprocessor should ignore does tokens and a 'post-preprocessor' can replace these `@@` back to newlines?

Comment: More or less — it means that whatever preprocessor technology you use will probably need non-standard lexical analysis. Remember that preprocessor behaves “as if” it follows the phases outlined in the standard.  The standard itself says that the steps are often combined. A compiler such as GCC does report which code caused a problem; it will point at one source line in a statement that was written over several lines with backslash-newline continuations.  What you want probably can be done, but may require considerable tweaking of standard preprocessor technology.  Wave may be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the first, and at least partly the second, using Boost.Wave. The key functionality is the [context policy hooks](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/wave/doc/class_reference_ctxpolicy.html), in particular `expanding_function_like_macro`, `expanding_object_like_macro`, and `rescanned_macro`. The first two give you the ability to conditionally suppress macro expansion, and the last gives you the result of a macro expansion.

Jonathan Leffler pointed out one reason your second requirement might not be fully met; I would add that I'm not certain "newline preservation" is something Wave has test coverage for or was designed to achieve. At any rate the `rescanned_macro` will give you the results of the expansion.

Comment: By mimicking a template engine using a smart combination of macro definitions and include directives, I have now solved in a more elegant and generic way my issue  without the need of anything but the C preprocesor. This includes a solution for the new line issue. However if you can provide a working example on what your describing here. I'll upvote and accept your answer.

Comment: It sounds like you have a solution that meets your needs, then! If anyone else is interested in this approach, Wave comes with a set of sample programs; the "advanced_hooks" one shows some of this functionality. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/wave/doc/samples.html